# Text with different styles in one paragraph Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

**I want to have bold** and not bold text in one line.

```vb
    With objWrdDoc
        .Styles.Add ("S2")
        .Styles.Add ("S3")
        .Styles("S2").Font.Bold = True
        .Styles("S3").Font.Bold = False
    End With
    With objWrdApp.Selection
        .TypeParagraph
        .Style = objWrdDoc.Styles("S2")
        .TypeText Text:="I want to have bold "
        .Style = objWrdDoc.Styles("S3")
        .TypeText Text:="and not bold text in one line."
    End With
```

As a result, the entire text is not bold.

Comment: When you call `.Style = objWrdDoc.Styles("S3")`, you're applying it to the whole selection including the first text that was entered.

Comment: @jsheeran How to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

While working with the `Selection` object feels "intuitive", it's not as accurate for writing code to manipulate Word as using `Range` objects. You can think about a `Range` as being an invisible selection, with the important differences that

- code can work with multiple `Range` objects
- the user can't affect where a `Range` is (clicking on the screen or pressing arrow keys changes a `Selection`)
- tracking where a `Range` is at any given point in the code is reliable

Changing the code in the question to work with a "target" `Range` could look as follows.

(Note that I've also added `Style` objects for the styles being defined. It's much more reliable and a lot less typing to work with objects, rather than constructs such as `objWrdDoc.Styles("S3")`.)

```
   Dim S2 as Word.Style, S3 as Word.Style 'As Object if using late-binding
   With objWrdDoc
        Set S2 = .Styles.Add("S2")
        Set S3 = .Styles.Add("S3")
        S2.Font.Bold = True
        S3.Font.Bold = False
    End With

    Dim objRange as Word.Range 'As Object if using late-binding
    Set objRange = objWrdApp.Selection.Range

    With objRange
        .Text = vbCr 'Chr(13) = paragraph mark
        'The new text should follow the inserted paragraph mark
        'Like pressing right-arrow to "collapse" a selection
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd

        'When working with ranges, apply the formatting after writing the text
        .Text = "I want to have bold "
        .Style = S2

        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Text = "and not bold text in one line."
        .Style = S3
    End With
```

Comment: The script is executed, but all the text is not bold.

Comment: *All* the text should not be bold, only the first part @aspire89.

Comment: @aspire89 Are you going to follow up on this?

Comment: I use Microsoft Word 2013 (15.0.5163.1000) MSO (15.0.5172.1000)
![screenshot](https://habrastorage.org/webt/ua/gs/0-/uags0-dca_fztvjibabgbpf_yhq.png)